# Change bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

please help to me: I would like to modify the ksfh_nat bibliography style in natbib.

Original:

[image]

I would like this:
[image]

It is possible to modify the style? Thanks for your help!

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}                      
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}

\begin{document}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\cite{cundall1979}

\medskip

\bibliographystyle{ksfh_nat}
\bibliography{demo.bib}
\end{document}
```

and the .bib file:

```
@article{cundall1979,
author  = "Cundall P.A.  and  Strack O.D.L.",
title   = "A discrete numerical model for granular assemblies",
journal =  "Geotechnique",
volume =   "322",
year =     "1905"
}
```

But, it isn't working, I don't get the expected result... Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a very short example including one entry from your bibliography? Just a basic .tex file with some text and the entry so other users don't have to type all from scratch.